# Cordova not showing splashscreen and icon

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 5 for a project.
After I build I dont see splashscreen or icons, are still the default.

I've installed splashscreen plugin for cordova too.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon.png" />
</platform>
```

Comment: No, my problem is that I'm seeing the default icons